# Spawn multiple threads each returning multiple values

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I am trying to spawn multiple threads that will perform a given task. This task differs depending on what is passed in and will return multiple values.

I've tried something along the following lines with no luck:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::thread, Task, Result1, Result2>> workers;
for (auto const& task : tasks) {
    Result1 result1;
    Result2 result2;
    std::tuple<std::thread, Task, Result1, Result2> worker = std::make_tuple(std::thread(&Slave::performTask, this, task, std::ref(result1), std::ref(result2)), task, result1, result2);
    workers.emplace_back(worker);
}
for (auto& w : workers) {
    std::get<0>(w).join();
    std::cout << "Task=" << std::get<1>(w) << " Result1=" << std::get<2>(w) << " Result2=" << std::get<3>(w) << std::endl; 
}
```

I believe the problem lies with referencing a std::thread in a nested container causing `workers.emplace_back(worker);` to be invalid. I tried using std::move in a few places with no success.

`workers.emplace_back(worker);` causes the following errors:

external/libcxx/include/thread:268:5: error: 'std::__1::thread::thread(const std::__1::thread&)' is private
     thread(const thread&);

external/libcxx/include/type_traits:887:87: error: within this context
         sizeof(__is_convertible_imp::__test<_T2>(__is_convertible_imp::__source<_T1>())) == 1

external/libcxx/include/type_traits:851:28: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'char std::__1::__is_convertible_imp::__test(_Tp) [with _Tp = std::__1::thread]'
 template  char  __test(_Tp);

As requested by Daniel, I have put together a minimal compile-able example. It compiles and executes correctly on cpp.sh:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using Task = std::string;
using Result1 = std::string;
using Result2 = std::string;

class Slave {
    private:
    void performTask(Task task, Result1& result1, Result2& result2) {
        if (task == "A") {
            result1 = "A1";
            result2 = "A2";
        } else if (task == "B") {
            result1 = "B1";
            result2 = "B2";
        } else {
            result1 = "C1";
            result2 = "C2";
        }
    }
    public:
    std::vector<Task> tasks;
    std::vector<std::tuple<Task, Result1, Result2>> performParallel() {
        std::vector<std::tuple<Task, Result1, Result2>> results;
        std::vector<std::tuple<std::thread, Task, std::unique_ptr<Result1>, std::unique_ptr<Result2>>> workers;
        for (auto const& task : tasks) {
            std::unique_ptr<Result1> result1(new Result1);
            std::unique_ptr<Result2> result2(new Result2);
            std::tuple<std::thread, Task, std::unique_ptr<Result1>, std::unique_ptr<Result2>> worker = std::make_tuple(std::move(std::thread(&Slave::performTask, this, task, std::ref(*result1), std::ref(*result2))), task, std::move(result1), std::move(result2));
            workers.emplace_back(std::move(worker));
        }
        for (auto& w : workers) {
            std::get<0>(w).join();
            std::tuple<Task, Result1, Result2> result = std::make_tuple(std::get<1>(w), *std::get<2>(w), *std::get<3>(w));
            results.emplace_back(result);
        }
        return results;
    }
};

int main() {
    Slave slave;
    slave.tasks = { "A", "B", "C" };
    std::vector<std::tuple<Task, Result1, Result2>> results = slave.performParallel();
    for (auto const& r : results) {
        std::cout << "Task=" << std::get<0>(r) << " Result1=" << std::get<1>(r) << " Result2=" << std::get<2>(r) << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Execution output:

> Task=A Result1=A1 Result2=A2
>
> Task=B Result1=B1 Result2=B2
>
> Task=C Result1=C1 Result2=C2

Comment: those `t`s in the bottom loop should be `w`s right?

Comment: Also, don't be afraid to use structs or classes.  a tuple of 4 items is crying out for names.

Comment: Please edit your question to include any error messages you may be seeing.

Comment: Yes, the `t`'s were supposed to be `w`s in the workers loop. I fixed the code sample in the question.

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal, compile-able, verifiable example along with a description of the intended behavior and the actually observed behavior.

Comment: Calling `workers.emplace_back(std::move(worker))` works with MSVC 2015. What compiler are you using?

Comment: You may consider std::future (returning a tuple as result)

Comment: @lcs I am compiling on AOSP (android-6.0.1_r30)

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes I, I have considered the use of std::future but I would like to get a std::thread implementation working first.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are not *copy constructible*, hence the error `'thread(const thread&)' is private`

Threads **are** *move constructible* though, so you can `emplace_back` an rvalue-reference by using `std::move`:

```
workers.emplace_back(std::move(worker));
```

Whilst this will solve the immediate problem, please note you have a larger, more sinister problem - namely **dangling references**

You are passing **references to temporaries** to your thread function, (and then creating a tuple with **copies** of `Result1` and `Result2`)

```
Result1 result1;
Result2 result2;

std::tuple<std::thread, Task, Result1, Result2> worker = 
    std::make_tuple(
        std::thread(
            &Slave::performTask, 
            this, 
            task, 
            std::ref(result1),  <-- here you pass a reference to a local variable
            std::ref(result2)), <-- 
        task, 
        result1,   <-- here you copy construct the tuple member from a local var
        result2);  <--
```

Your thread will be referencing dangling references to `result1` and `result2`, and will likely seg-fault.

You **could** create the tuple with an empty thread object first, and then create the thread passing references to the tuple members, but I wouldn't suggest this.

A better design would be to use some encapsulation, packaging up your thread and the result variables in their own class

```
struct Worker
{
    Worker(Task& task)
        : task(task)
        , _thread(&Worker::performTask, this)
    {
    }

    void performTask()
    {
        result1 = task.foo();
        result2 = task.bar();
    }

    void join()
    {
        _thread.join();
    }

    Task    task;
    Result1 result1;
    Result2 result2;

private:
    std::thread _thread;
};
```

Now you don't have to try create the tuple with the `Result` variables **and** pass references to the thread tuple member.

Comment: You made some good points. I believe I addressed some of these as I was putting together a compile-able code sample. Take a look at the code I added to my question.

Comment: I really recommend you embrace OOD and encapsulate your workers into a Worker class. It will make your code much easier to reason about. You also won't necessarily need to make your Result objects pointers in order to ensure their lifetime outlasts your loop.
The creation of your workers will be so much simpler - `workers.emplace_back(task);` - done.

Comment: I am still considering your suggestion of refactoring the code to improve encapsulation. My main hesitation is creating a class that would only be used in this specific case, but perhaps that is the correct approach.

Comment: @Snooze Why *wouldn't* you create a class? You're encapsulating everything required to "do the work" into a single "worker" class.

Comment: I will try that approach tomorrow and see how it turns out. The code sample in the question is just a trivial example since I cannot share the original. Hopefully refactoring will eliminate the compiler errors I'm seeing on AOSP. Thanks for your feedback!